# when we combine char array with strings in pritln method why char array will converted into byte code in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public class Afgh {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            String s2=new String("Thisissurya");
            char[] buf= new char[30];
            s2.getChars(0,4,buf,0);
            System.out.println(buf);
            }

    }
```

it will give output correctly : This
but if we change code 
when we write like this

```
public class Afgh {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            String s2=new String("Techfortelangana");
            char[] buf= new char[30];
            s2.getChars(0,4,buf,0);
            System.out.println("the chars are :"+buf);
            }

    }
```

but it will giving as output:
the chars are :[C@138532dc
why char array directly converted into string?? when concatenating??!

Answer (score 1):

That's not `ByteCode` you are directly printing Character array which is printing *array reference as String* which is  a String representation of the Array.

Use `Arrays.toString(array)` or Iterate over array to print array elements.

```
[C@138532dc
```

- `[C` `C` means Character class `[` means array
- `@` at the rate character
- `138532dc` `hashcode` of `Object` Converted to `HexaDecimal String`

Answer (score 0):

In the first case `System.out.println(buf);` you are calling a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28char%5B%5D%29) specific for a `char[]`.

In the second case, you are performing string concatenation which uses the default toString implementation of the object being concatenated. In this case, being an array, you get the array reference.

If you want to turn into a String, you will need to do so manually.